# Android Studio no connected device problem

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter

I have a freshly installed android studio on my PC for flutter development, but I am facing this issue.

As seen in the photo the virtual device shows up.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mcGs0qxKVZafD4j0J02n44n-3fbu1iHR

but it shows loading in the android studio toolbar.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yJ18a7DL4Livfc31pKryXrRJCUjkO1hW

when I try to run the application this message shows up

https://drive.google.com/open?id=18cWfhtbh4M9Nkn8KQAaRRSvLi8R0DPMR

but when I run "flutter doctor" everything seems to be fine.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E6MoIvWEnwFjOl-E_gjYQAjxJSlvs6fz

though if try to run it using "flutter run" nothing happens it just gets stuck on "running gradle task"

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f6D1V63c06uu6LyY077zP6DLkEkggnTN

Comment: Can you wait for some more time after running `flutter run` command and wait for the output in console/app?

Comment: I've tried waiting for like 20mins. Should wait more?

Answer (score 0):

for android device, I solved it using this :

```
flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk
```

not sure if it'll work with iOS devices as well.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zYYWL7DD12-vzL99VwPAehL_KLoSRuDw                                                  now its not able to locate android sdk and shows no devies connected.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your studio is loading current active device.

On top there are four option:

1) One is for on which active device you want to run apk(phone icon available).

2) Second is represent starting point of app(flutter logo icon).

3) Total device available.

4) last on run app

so please check first option where studio find active device.

Comment: As you can see in the second photo, it shows loading and stays like that

Comment: yes, i check all photo. if loading taking long time then invalidate cache and restart studio

Comment: Its still the same. Actually as I followed "Niraj's" advice, now flutter is not able to locate the sdk as you can see in the photo.